# TypeError: Notifications.getPermissionsAsync is not a function. Expo Notifications

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, expo-notifications

I'm trying to send `push` notifications using `expo-notifications`. I'm using the example in the [`documentation`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#installation) and it works very well with `javascript`. When I try it in `typescript` it gives me the error:

```bash
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Notifications.getPermissionsAsync is not a function. (In 'Notifications.getPermissionsAsync()', 'Notifications.getPermissionsAsync' is undefined)]
```

Here is my `code`

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View, Platform } from "react-native";
import * as Device from "expo-device";
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
//   handleNotification: async () => ({
//     shouldShowAlert: true,
//     shouldPlaySound: false,
//     shouldSetBadge: false,
//   }),
// });

const sendPushNotification = async (expoPushToken: any) => {
  const message = {
    to: expoPushToken,
    sound: "default",
    title: "Test title",
    body: "Test body",
    data: { testData: "test data" },
  };

  await fetch("https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(message),
  });
};
export default function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState();

  console.log({ token });

  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    if (mounted) {
      (async () => {
        if (Device.isDevice) {
          const { status: existingStatus } =
            await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
          let finalStatus = existingStatus;
          if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
            const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
            finalStatus = status;
          }
          if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
            alert("Failed to get push token for push notification!");
            return;
          }
          const { data } = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
          setToken(data as any);
        } else {
          alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
        }

        if (Platform.OS === "android") {
          Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
            name: "default",
            importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
            vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
            lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
          });
        }
      })();
    }

    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      {token && (
        <Button onPress={() => sendPushNotification(token)} title="Send" />
      )}
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

So what may be possibly the problem, because it seems like everything is fine when i'm using `javascript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be with the typings for the expo notifications module. Ensure that you have the latest version of the library installed, and if the issue still persists, try importing it as:

```js
import Notifications from 'expo-notifications/src/Notifications'
```

instead of:

```
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications'
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Starnec, I however resolve the issue by importing `Notifications` from the `node_modules` stack as follows. `import * as Notifications from "./node_modules/expo-notifications/src";`

Comment: You're welcome, happy the problem was resolved, good luck

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the error by importing `Notifications` from the `expo-notifications` stack inside node modules as follows.

```
// App.tsx
import * as Notifications from "./node_modules/expo-notifications/src";
```

Good Luck.